# What is the best way to manage localization in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, i18next

I wrote a small application in `Vue 3` which handle the localization using `i18n@next`. My implementation is pretty simple, essentially I have each url prefixed with the current locale chosen by the user.

**main.ts**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import { i18n } from './lang'

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .use(i18n)
  .mount('#app')
```

**lang/index.ts**

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import en from './translations/en.json'
import it from './translations/it.json'

export const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages: {
    en,
    it,
  },
})
```

**router/index.ts**

```
import { i18n } from '@/lang'
import { useAuth } from '@/modules/auth'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'

function load(component: string) {
  return () => import(`@/views/${component}.vue`)
}

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'root',
    redirect: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE,
  },
  {
    path: '/:locale',
    component: App,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      const locale = to.params.locale.toString()
      const supportedLocales = process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_SUPPORTED_LOCALE.split(
        ','
      )

      if (!supportedLocales.includes(locale)) return next('en')

      if (i18n.global.locale !== locale) {
        i18n.global.locale = locale
      }

      return next()
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'home',
        component: load('Home'),
        meta: { requiresAuth: false },
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        name: 'login',
        component: load('Auth/Login'),
        meta: { requiresAuth: false },
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        name: 'register',
        component: load('Auth/Register'),
        meta: { requiresAuth: false },
      },
    ],
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const { authenticating, user } = useAuth()
  next()
})

export default router
```

Essentially I can have multiple urls like:

```
http://localhost:8080/en
http://localhost:8080/en/login
http://localhost:8080/it
http://localhost:8080/it/login
```

As you can see from `router/index.ts`, before enter into an url, I set the locale available in the prefix.

I also have this `LanguageSwitcher.vue` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown ms-3">
    <a
      class="dropdown-toggle"
      href="#"
      role="button"
      id="dropdownLanguage"
      data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false"
    >
      <img class="fa-fw me-2" src="assets/images/flags/uk.svg" alt="" />
      {{ $i18n.locale }}
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu mt-2 shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownLanguage">
      <span class="dropdown-item-text">{{ $t("selectLanguage") }}</span>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a
        class="dropdown-item"
        v-for="(lang, i) in langs"
        :key="`lang-${i}`"
        v-on:click="changeLanguage(lang)"
      >
        <img class="fa-fw me-2" src="assets/images/flags/uk.svg" alt="" />
        {{ lang }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "LanguageSwitcher",
  data() {
    return { langs: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_SUPPORTED_LOCALE.split(",") }
  },
  methods: {
    changeLanguage(lang) {
      this.$i18n.locale = lang

      // replace url prefix with the selected locale
      this.$router.replace({ params: { locale: lang } })
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

The code above works well but I have few questions:

1. **Static assets issue**:

Each `URL` is prefixed with the locale chosen by the user. So for load the static assets, I was forced to use this convention in `index.html` (which is located in the public directory):

```
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is different with the components. Infact I have something like this:

```
<img
    class="navbar-brand-item"
    v-bind:src="assets/images/logo.png"
    alt="Logo"
    />
```

when this asset is loaded I get `200` as status code, but nothing is returned back 'cause there is the locale prefix:

```
http://localhost:8080/en/assets/images/logo.png
```

How can I load the assets and load everything from:

```
http://localhost:8080/assets/images/logo.png
```

I also tried to add a `@/assets` but same issue, infact I get:

```
http://localhost:8080/@/en/assets/images/logo.png
```

Some example from console:

[image]

[image]

2. **Localize the slug**:

How can I translate also the url? Eg: if I'm on `english` locale, and the load something like `http://localhost:8080/en/login` when I go to `italian` locale I just get `http://localhost:8080/it/login`, so the same slug with the prefix changed. Is there a way to also translate the slug?

Something like: `http://localhost:8080/it/accedi`. In this way the italian user can understand the page where they are located.

3. **router-link not follow the prefix**

Suppose I have:

```
<router-link class="nav-link" to="/login">
    Login <i class="far fa-user me-2"></i>
</router-link>
```

if the current url is: `http://localhost:8080/en` and I click on the `login` link, I get: `http://localhost:8080/login` but should be: `http://localhost:8080/en/login`. How can I manage this?

Comment: *Each URL is prefixed with the locale chosen by the user* - this problem doesn't generally exist in Vue SPA because libs are preferably imported or served from CDN, not from local vendor folder. Use base tag for that.  *v-bind:src="assets/images/logo.png"* - it's supposed to be `src="@/assets/images/logo.png"`, no v-bind because it's not a variable. *How can I translate also the url* - you can use catch-all route and do all routing there. Not sure if there's a way to do this that is not hacky. Probably register all localized route paths beforehand in a loop. I doubt it's worth the effort.

Comment: @EstusFlask what if I have: `<img class="navbar-brand-item" :src=" !isNavbarLight ? 'assets/images/logo-light.png' : 'assets/images/logo.png'" alt="Logo" />`? and why do you think routing translation isn't worth?

Comment: I didn't check but I suppose that src should be statically analyzed on compilation to bundle an image. Use two img with v-if and no bindings on src, or import image url explicitly, see https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html .

Comment: I don't remember I've ever seen translated static (login, etc) routes on any considerable website, including the ones with non-English speaking audience. This is a subject for UX study but I don't think users pay that much attention to urls so it could justify jumping through hoops, which will surely take place. On the other hand, it happened to me more than once that I had to navigated a website in wrong locale by looking at English urls, also needed to substitute language url segment to force it to another locale.